# QuickSort Scheme

Tags: sorting, scheme, quicksort

I need to implement the following quicksort: 
(quick-sort pred lst)
lst is the list of numbers to be sorted
pred is the predicate by which the list is ordered, the signature of this predicate is:
(lambda (x y) …)

the code here is working but the problem here that when i get in lst the same number more then once im entering to infinite loop, after hours of debugging i cant find the problem or how to solve it.

```
(define (quick-sort pred lst)

;Pivot is 1st element of the list
 (define (pivot lst)
  (if (or (null? lst) (= 1 (length lst)))
    'done
     (car lst)))

 partition get the pivot the list and the predicate and splitting it to two lists
  (define (partition piv lst pred)

    ;predPos is the pred it slef and predNeg is the negative of the pred
     (let* ((predPos (lambda (x) (pred x piv) )) 
            (predNeg (lambda (x) (if (pred x piv) #f #t)))

            ;Filtering the big list in to two lists
            (p1 (filter predPos lst))
            (p2 (filter predNeg lst)))

          ;Recursivly doing the qucicksort on each list. and joining them together.
           (cond ((and (null? p1) (null? p2)) (cons piv ()))
                 ((null? p1) (quick-sort pred p2))
                 ((null? p2) (quick-sort pred p1))
                 (else (joiner (quick-sort pred p1) (quick-sort pred p2))))))


      ;Joining 2 lists together
      (define (joiner p1 p2)
      (cond ((null? p1) p2)
            ((null? p2) p1)
            (else (cons  (car p1) (joiner (cdr p1) p2)))))

 ;The main quicksort method () and list size one are sorted!
 (let ((piv (pivot lst)))
   (if (or (null? lst) (= 1 (length lst)))
      lst
      (partition piv lst pred))))
```

Comment: "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance."  Please show **an example of the input, how you're calling the procedure, and the results**.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the pivot before partitioning, you are guaranteed to make progress at each recursive step. Without this measure the pivot will stick at the front of its partition and you won't get anywhere.

Comment: do you mean to call the pivot function inside the partitioning and not befor? or you mean to remove it from list? and then add him?

Comment: Remove it from the list and then add it back. Specifically, give `partition` the list without the pivot, i.e. `(cdr lst)`, and add the pivot when you join the two halves.

Comment: Ok i got you, but if choose the pivot randomly? and not like this algorithm here who take the 1st element, how do i know what to remove?

Comment: You can replace the pivot with the first element (using `set-car!`), and then you can remove the pivot easily. Note that this mutates the original list. It is possible instead to create a new list without the pivot: `(define (without i lst) (if (= i 0) (cdr lst) (cons (car lst) (without (- i 1) (cdr lst)))))`